# Accessing a variable declared within a function within a class (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, class, scope, superglobals

I am working on a script for a site where users can create accounts and upload data, which can later be searched and accessed by the public.  As part of my upload class, I have a function to rename the file so that there aren't multiple files with the same name in my uploads directory.  The problem is that I need to get that renamed file value out of the class so that I can drop it into the fileName part of my mySQL database.

The code for the function that really does the work in the class:

```
class Ds1_Upload {
protected $_uploaded = array();
protected $_destination;
protected $_max = 10485760;
protected $_messages = array();
protected $_permitted = array('audio/mpeg','audio/wav','audio/mpeg3','audio/x-mpeg-3');
protected $_renamed = false;

public function __construct($path) {
    if(!is_dir($path) || !is_writable($path)) {
        throw new Exception("$path must be a valid, writable directory.");
    }
    $this->_destination = $path;
    $this->_uploaded = $_FILES;
}


public function move($overwrite = false) {
    $field = current($this->_uploaded);
    $OK = $this->checkError($field['name'], $field['error']);
    if($OK) {
        $sizeOK = $this->checkSize($field['name'],$field['size']);
        $typeOK = $this->checkType($field['name'], $field['type']);
        if($sizeOK && $typeOK) {
            $name = $this->checkName($field['name'], $overwrite);
            $success = move_uploaded_file($field['tmp_name'], $this->_destination.$name);

            if($success) {

                $message = $field['name']. ' was uploaded successfully';
                if ($this->_renamed) {
                    $message .=" and renamed $name as a result of a conflicting filename in the Sleep Speak database.";
                }

                $this->_messages[] = $message;
            } else {
                $this->_messages[] = 'Could not upload ' . $field['name'];
            }
            $_POST['dream'] = $name;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have tried to make it set a $_POST variable equal to the value for $name (which is the value that I need), but when I try to set the fileName column in my main code using $_POST['dream'], it returns a page that says "column fileName cannot be null."  Is there an issue with setting superglobals within a function or within a class?  If so, what can I do to get the value of $name out of the class to be accessible with a mySQL query?

Here is the mySQL code

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "fileupload")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO Dreams (fileName, userName, dreamName, tags,     uploadDate) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['dream'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['title'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tags'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['date'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_Sleep_Speak, $Sleep_Speak);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $Sleep_Speak) or die(mysql_error());


}
```

All of the other $_POST values are set by a form being submitted.  $_POST['dreams'] is initiated by the form from a hidden field but it isn't actually set to anything.  Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong here?  I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the complete flow of code, I would suggest that you change your last line of code in the move() function from:

```
$_POST['dream'] = $name;
```

To:

```
return $name;
```

And then capture the return value like so:

```
$filename = $upload->move();
```

Then, change this line:

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['dream'], "text"),
```

To:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($filename),
```